# Create comment system in microsoft access?

Tags: ms-access

Would anybody have any idea how to create comment system in microsoft access? I'm sorry that I don't have any code to show you but I have no idea how to do this. 
Just a simple comments like they would have at the end of any article online would help so much.
Thanks

Comment: Create a new db using one of the provided templates, e.g. Support db. There are such samples in the code.

Comment: Just create a table. Make a 1:M relationship with whatever parent entity they are related to. Example: PhotoTbl PhotoCommentsTbl(would have PhotoID as FK)